# Golang XML: how to get xml attribute in header in string map

Tags: xml, go, soap, encoding

Suppose, I have an XML like this

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <contents>
            <article>
                <category>Server</category>
                <title>Connect to Oracle Server using Golang and Go-OCI8 on Ubuntu</title>
                <url>/go-oci8-oracle-linux/</url>
            </article>
            <article>
                <category>Server</category>
                <title>Easy Setup OpenVPN Using Docker DockVPN</title>
                <url>/easy-setup-openvpn-docker/</url>
            </article>
            <article info="popular article">
                <category>Server</category>
                <title>Setup Ghost v0.11-LTS, Ubuntu, Nginx, Custom Domain, and SSL</title>
                <url>/ghost-v011-lts-ubuntu-nginx-custom-domain-ssl/</url>
            </article>
        </contents>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How to get a map that return the attribute at the root element (the key value is dynamic, not always `xmlns:soap` and `xmlns:ns`)

`{ "xmlns:soap": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "xmlns:ns": "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" }`

and also how to get this string `soap:Envelope`?

assuming structure is not always `soap:Envelope`, so it can be `soap:Foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "encoding/xml"

var input = []byte(`
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
</soap:Envelope>
`)

func main() {
   var soap struct {
      Attrs   []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
      XMLName xml.Name
   } 
   err := xml.Unmarshal(input, &soap)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   println(soap.Attrs[1].Name.Local == "ns")
   println(soap.Attrs[1].Value == "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
   println(soap.XMLName.Local == "Envelope")
}
```

Comment: btw how to get string "soap:Envelop" ? `soap.XMLName.Local` only return "Envelope"

Comment: `soap.XMLName.Space` will give the actual namespace (eg: `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`). You can then inspect `xmlns` attributes (through `Attrs`) to find which alias was used for it (`soap` in that case). I am not sure why you would like to retrieve the aliases though.

Comment: Point being, it could very well be `<foobar:Envelope xmlns:foobar="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
</foobar:Envelope>` and that would be the exact same thing from a semantical perspective.